# Using x264 Win binary in Ubuntu

Tags: executable

I like to work with standalone CLI binaries whether .jar or .exe
Standalone .jar CLIs like PDFBox by Apache is cross platform & can be use in Win & *nix similarly, however...
I currently use x264_32_tMod-8bit-all-libav.exe standalone .exe but I can't use this under Ubuntu, so is there any standalone CLI executable .bin available for Ubuntu which can be used via terminal. 
All tutorials refer to Handbrake & FFmpeg compiling but I am more comfortable with x264 syntax

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using avconv/ffmpeg, but if you're more comfortable with x264 by itself, you can install it form the repositories

```
sudo apt-get install x264
```